# Why isn't aircrack identifying my wireless interface?

Tags: wireless, command-line, aircrack-ng

I have installed aircrack and when trying to identify a wireless network interface (after executing `/sbin/iwconfig` in the terminal) I get the following.

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NETGEAR-3G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: C0:3F:0E:9F:BE:E0   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:24 dBm   
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=5/5  Signal level=-20 dBm  Noise level=-94 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I have WiFi on my Laptop and I see other wireless connections available to connect to.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has already identified `eth1` as the wireless interface (says 802.11). You're on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

To start using aircrack you have to change you wifi card mode to `Monitor` if your wifi card support that.